# How to use spring data mongo @CompoundIndex with sub collections?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Assume that I have such entities like the following:

```
@Document(collection = "doc_a")
public class A {    
  @Field("id")
  private Integer id;

  @Field("b")
  private Collection<B> b;
  ...
}


public class B {    
  @Field("id")
  private Integer id;
  ...
}
```

is it possible to use a compoundIndex with respect to A.id AND B.id together?

I mean maybe like:

```
@CompoundIndex(name = "aid_bid_idx", def = "{'id', 'b.id'}")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried it? It doesn't work?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, in our environment it is quite hard to understand whether indexes are created and working successfully or not. Mongodb responsibility is owned by our architect, and nowadays he is not available. That's why I wanted to ask first from here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've tried this kind of compound index in my app, that use spring data too, and worked properly.
You only have to correct the index definition in `@CompoundIndex` annotation:

```
@CompoundIndex(name = "aid_bid_idx", def = "{'id' : 1, 'b.id' : 1}")
@Document(collection = "doc_a")
public class A {    
  @Field("id")
  private Integer id;

  @Field("b")
  private Collection<B> b;
  ...
}

public class B {    
  @Field("id")
  private Integer id;
  ...
}
```

If you run a query with explain (like the follows) in mongo shell, you'll see that the index *aid_bid_idx* will be used.

```
db.doc_a.find({ "id" : 1, "b.id" : 1}).explain()
```

The result will be something like this:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor aid_bid_idx",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx for providing the example with "explain()".

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, for me the Miguel's solution worked but I had to wrap the @CompoundIndex inside a @CompoundIndexes otherwise it didn't work (I'm using Spring Roo).

```
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "aid_bid_idx", def = "{'id' : 1, 'b.id' : 1}")
})
@Document(collection = "doc_a")
public class A {...}
```

Comment: I think CompounIndex directly will also work. One thing that was missing in the documentation is they fail to mention when the indexes will be created post introducing them in the code block. After playing around it for a while, i see that indexes are getting created only after inserting a new document post introducing them in the code.

Comment: it doesn't work with only single `CompoundIndex`

Answer (score 0):

> @CompoundIndexes({
> @CompoundIndex(name = "aid_bid_idx", def = "{'id' : 1, 'b.id' : 1}") }) @Document(collection = "doc_a") public class A {...}

In this snippet, it's better to have the `value` attribute for the `@CompoundIndexes` annotation and if it's unique, then mark it as `unique=true`. Such as, along with the usage of lombok:

```
@Data
@CompoundIndexes(value = {
   @CompoundIndex(name = "aid_bid_idx", def = "{'id' : 1, 'b.id' : 1}", unique = true)}) 
@Document(collection = "doc_a") 
public class A {...implementation...}
```

Comment: doesn't work, tried it