# @Indexed on nested property not working in Spring-data for mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following object structure:

```
@Document(collection = "user")
@TypeAlias("user")
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private Contact info = new Contact();
}
```

and here is the Contact pojo:

```
public class Contact {
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String mail;
}
```

But for some reasons not known to me, I don't see Spring-data creating a unique index for the property **info.mail**

To summarize, I have this json structure of user object:
**{_id:xxxxx,info:{mail:"abc@xyz.shoes"}}**

And I want to create a unique index on **info.mail** using Spring data with the above pojo structure. Please help.

Comment: which version of spring-data-mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as I remember, annotating embedded fields with @Indexed will not work. @CompoundIndex is the way to go:

```java
@Document(collection = "user")
@TypeAlias("user")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "contact_email", def = "{ 'contact.mail': 1 }", unique = true)
})
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private Contact info = new Contact();
}
```

Comment: Could you please guide me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948943/spring-data-mongo-apply-unique-combination-fields-in-embedded-document

Comment: If necessary, you may have to use the `@Field` annotation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14054004/5943840). But it works fine without it for me if I remove the outer `@CompoundIndexes` tag and only use the `@CompoundIndex` annotation.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had a fresh spring boot application 2.3.0 with just @Document, @Id and @Indexed annotations. I was able to retrieve and insert documents but it refused to create the index other than the PK. Finally I figured that there is a property that you need to enable.

`spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation = true`

As a matter of fact it even works on nested objects without @Document annotation.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: For 'AbstractMongoClientConfiguration', that is 'public boolean autoIndexCreation() ' which is false by default.

Answer (score 7):

> Obsolete answer, this was with and older version of mongodb 1.x.

---

Had the same issue, it seems that your `Contact` class is missing the `@Document` annotation i.e.

```
@Document
public class Contact {
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String mail;
}
```

Should work, quote from the [spring mongodb reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage)

> Automatic index creation is only done for types annotated with @Document.

Comment: I think that any embedded document doesn't require @Document because it's not a real document, but just a filed of a Document.

Comment: Sure, but you still have to hint the Spring MongoDB DSL implementation about how to transform and use the classes it it supposed to *index*. 

The Spring MongoDB will parse the classes internally for every class that use the `@Document` annotation and apply the `@Indexed` option for it.
 
You can apply automatic `index` through the *mongo* console or via *java code*  if you want. But if you want to benefit from the automatic stuff that Spring does for you, you just have to follow the rules in the documentation :P

Comment: Otherwise it would be kind of hard for the *Spring Mongo* implementation, to just parse all the java files in the embedded code and check all the fields for every class that is annotated with the `@Indexed` annotation. The larger the code base the more time it would take. 

So the reason they have `@Document` is to hint the *Spring Mongo* implementation about which files to check for and apply the `@Indexed` option if set.

Comment: I meant that you don't need to add any annotation in the embedded document. If you need to index a field of an embedded document  you should use @CompoundIndex on the parent class.

Comment: Kind of find it strange the docs for *Spring Mongo* clearly show all the examples of the usage `@CompoundIndex`  in conjunction with usage of the `@Docucment` annotation.

Comment: Ok i get what you are saying extend a parent class with a `@Document` annotation. Sure that would work but that's more a coding/style choice. I Prefer to have each base `@Document` class that goes into *mongodb* as a final class that does not have any inheritance.

Comment: @cristobal
Why is that index is created each time a Mongo Connection is established using Indexed on a class property? Doesn't this cause an overload on the Database?
I can see in the logs that indexes are created each time.

Comment: @Adnan the spring mongo db driver i was using then is for an old mongo db impl. 

As far from your question i can't remember that happening. It may happen that this answer does not apply to the spring mongodb driver and the mongodb version you are currently using.

Comment: @Adnan sorry for the late reply, this answer was for an older mongo db driver and I have marked the answer as obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Xenobius's answer:

If any configuration extending `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` is set, `MongoMappingContext` will back off. The result is:

`spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation = true` **will not be effective**

You will need add this into your own configuration:

```java
    @Override
    protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
        return true;
    }
```

ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28478#issuecomment-954627106